# Collision probability by density integration

Tags: probability, integration, statistics

$\newcommand{\icol}[1]{% inline column vector
  \left(\begin{smallmatrix}#1\end{smallmatrix}\right)%
}$

Let's consider a road segment of length $l$ on which there is always 1 single car circulating at a constant speed $V_{car_1}$ (this means that cars are always spaced by the distance $l$).
Now imagine that someone is crossing the road at a constant speed $V_{car_2}$ with an intersection angle $\theta$.

Both cars are assumed to have a square shape of length $\lambda$

[Scenario Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvZTa.png)

The probability to have a collision is approximated by the following formula:
$$P_{collision} = \frac{2 \lambda}{l}\left(1+ \frac{|V_{car_1}-V_{car_2}cos(\theta)|}{V_{car_2}sin (\theta)}\right)$$

We have tried to model the similar probability using a different method. We have obtained the probability density function $f$ describing the occupancy probability of the car 1: $f(x,y)$ gives you the probability of the center of the car 1 being at coordinates $(x , y)$.

Let's consider $C_2 = \icol{x_2\\y_2}$ the coordinates of the car 2, we have:
$$
C_2(t) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
    x_{2_0}+V_2 cos(\theta) t\\
 y_{2_0}+V_2 sin(\theta) t
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I thought that the probability of collision would be the following:
$$
\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty} \int\limits_{y_2(t)-\lambda}^{y_2(t)+\lambda} \int\limits_{x_2(t)-\lambda}^{x_2(t)+\lambda} {f\left(x, y\right) \,dx\,dy\,dt}
$$
But somehow the obtained results are different.

For example considering both cars of size $\lambda=3$ running at $V_1=V_2=10m/s$ crossing at a $\theta = 90deg$ and taking $l=100m$ gives:
$$
\\ P_{collision\_method\_1} = 0.12
\\ P_{collision\_method\_2} = 0.036
$$

Where is my method wrong and what should I do to obtain the correct result with the method 2?

The code is available as a python notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Ofd7zlYNtbmNjwAHp6dGIkG0sI7o7aNK?usp=sharing

Update:

When $\Theta = 90deg$, we have:
$$
P_{collision\_method\_1} =  \frac{(V_1+V_2) V_2}{2V_1\lambda} P_{collision\_method\_2}
$$
This does not work well for other intersection angles. My best guess is that a $sin \theta$ or $cos \theta$ should also intervene in the scaling factor.

Answer (score 0):

[image: The method I think is correct(left | Your method (right)]Regarding your first question "Where is my method wrong":
The way you gave the borders of the integrals of x and y it seems to me that you assume that car 2 is parallel to the road at all times.
Then at a given timepoint t you integrate correctly.
However I think car 2 should be at the angle (here $\theta$) to the road. This complicates the borders of integration substantially, as depending on the angle the shape of the intersection should have different forms.
I did not manage to calculate them myself, in the picture you see what I believe to be your method on the right and the way I perceive the task on the left.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While I agree with your comment, I expect the difference between the 2 methods to be "quite small" (of course depending on the scenario). Typically for an intersection at 90deg this should not matter at all...